Use of named argument in R function t.test (and some others)
Using the argument formula explicitly (formula =  some formula) in t.test is not working on most R versions from 3.6.3 (and maybe even before, not tested) up to current 4.4.2.
The same happens with wilcox.test but not with lm or oneway.test.
The help page for t.test provides this example
 t.test(extra ~ group, data = sleep)

If we type
 t.test(data = sleep,  extra ~ group)

it also works, but
 t.test(data = sleep, formula = extra ~ group)

does not, producing an error that leads to think on a parsing argument issue:

Error in t.test.default(data = sleep, formula = extra ~ group) :
argument "x" is missing, with no default

Is this an expected behavior?

This is an issue with generic methods. lm and oneway.test are not generic methods. They are simply functions. Note that the generic method has to match the specific method to be called using the FIRST argument passed.

This is already on R's bugzilla.

This is arguably an R bug, or at least an "infelicity".
t.test is a generic function:
> stats::t.test
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("t.test")

From Wickham's Advanced R section 13.4:

Method dispatch is performed by UseMethod(), which every generic calls. UseMethod() takes two arguments: the name of the generic function (required), and the argument to use for method dispatch (optional). If you omit the second argument, it will dispatch based on the first argument, which is almost always what is desired.

(emphasis added)
So, what happens when you call t.test(data = sleep, formula = extra ~ group) ? The generic function looks at its first argument, which is a data frame, so it dispatches to t.test.default() (the only other option is t.test.formula: see methods("t.test"). That function (args(stats:::t.test.default)) is expecting an argument named x and can't find it ... (it throws an error the first time the value of x is evaluated)

methods are supposed to have consistent argument names with the generic but in this case the generic uses x and the method uses formula.  This inconsistency seems like a bug but it may be that due to backwards compatibility that no one wants to fix it.

Then why does it work without naming explicitly the formula, that is, t.test(data = sleep, extra ~ group) works as expected ?

I have to admit that I don't know why t.test appears to dispatch on the second argument if it is unnamed ... this might be a higher mystery to be asked on r-devel@r-project.org ... it might be explicable by close enough reading of the Method Dispatch section of the R language manual, but I couldn't figure it out ...

It seems it dispatches on the first unnamed argument, if any; otherwise, if they are all named then formula must be listed first in the call.

the formula is still the first unnamed argument, sum(na.rm = TRUE, 1:3) works the same way

sum is primitive rather than generic.

@G.Grothendieck im not sure why you think that matters t.test(subset = mpg > 10, na.action = 'na.pass', data = mtcars, mpg ~ vs)

Primitives do not use UseMethod which is what this is all about.  If it happens to work the same in some instances that is irrelevant.
